# Protecting encryption keys using DPAPI: Obvious hole?

Tags: .net, security, encryption, dpapi

I have a Windows.Forms based .NET desktop application that stores privileged information in a file on disk (not using .NET configuraton files), encrypted using a symmetric cryptography algorithm such as TripleDES using MS's CryptoAPI.  This file must be read/written over multiple program runs / machine power cycles, aka, use the same Key/IV every time. The obvious question here is how to protect the Key (and possibly IV), and several questions here on SO simply say "use the DPAPI" and give a trivial example of round trip encryption/decryption.

I know how to use the DPAPI already, but it seems there is an obvious problem with using it to protect a Key/IV to be fed to another encryption scheme. Consider the following code:

```
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider^ cryptoprov = gcnew TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider;
cryptoprov->Key = ProtectedData::Unprotect(encryptedKey, salt, DataProtectionScope::CurrentUser);
cryptoprov->IV  = ProtectedData::Unprotect(encryptedIV,  salt, DataProtectionScope::CurrentUser);
```

Due to the fact you must assign a SymmetricAlgorithm derived class' Key and IV, couldn't an attacker just set a breakpoint on this point, and easily figure out what the Key/IV is?

My questions are as follows:

- Have I missed the point for using DPAPI to protect keys? How would you do it?
- Should I just use the DPAPI for the encryption of my file? Therefore, no Key/IV storage needed.
- I've noticed the existence of CspParameters for asymmetric encryption. Is this inherently a better option than symmetrical?  (within the context of my scenario, not symmetric vs assymetric outright)

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you have good reasons, you should be using Rijndael, not TripleDES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of DPAPI is to protect persistant data from snooping and tampering, it offers nothing to protect tha secret data in the application's memory.

Answer (score 3):

If the attacker is able to set a breakpoint, you've already lost.
The attacker can simply set a breakpoint after the data is decrypted and read the plaintext.

What kind of attacker are you afraid of?

If you want to, you can write `if (Debugger.IsAttached) Environment.FailFast()`, but the attacker can remove the check using Reflexil.

Comment: Yes, good point, who would care to go after the key to decrypt something if they could just see it post decryption...

I suppose I am trying to thwart the casual/curious user who wants to find sensitive info out, but trying to protect against a dedicated person seems like a huge waste of time.

Comment: Who is the attacker? An admin on the system? Someone on the network? Someone else?

Comment: Someone with physical access to a machine with the software running, with a user left logged in. Lets say the legitimate user has stepped away and not locked the system, and some riff-raff steps up to it. They have the same credentials as the user running our software.

Comment: Then `if (Debugger.IsAttached) Environment.FailFast()`, sprinkled throughout the code, is probably enough.